# aws s3 - object has no attribute 'server_side_encryption'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

Can someone please explain the differences in these two calls. The first one gives the correct server_side_encryption and the second one gives an error. The other attributes give the same value-

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3
import botocore

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


object = s3.Object('abcdefhkjl9999','error.html')

print(object.bucket_name)
print(object.key)
print(object.last_modified)
print(object.storage_class)
print(object.server_side_encryption)


bucket = s3.Bucket('abcdefhkjl9999')
for object in bucket.objects.all():
    print("#############################")
    print(object.bucket_name)
    print(object.key)
    print(object.last_modified)
    print(object.storage_class)
    print(object.server_side_encryption)


The output is -
abcdefhkjl9999
error.html
2017-08-20 22:58:02+00:00
REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
aws:kms
#############################
abcdefhkjl9999
error.html
2017-08-20 22:58:02+00:00
REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test3.py", line 26, in <module>
print(object.server_side_encryption)
AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute       'server_side_encryption'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error you received states, the object you're trying to get the `server_side_encryption` attribute from is not, in fact, of the type `s3.Object`, but rather of the type `s3.ObjectSummary`

Fortunately you can get the object as a sub-resource as [specified here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ObjectSummary.Object)

`inner =  outer.Object()`
Then query for the property

`print(inner.server_side_encryption)`

Answer (score 2):

[s3.Object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) returns [Object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object)

[bucket.objects](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) returns [ObjectSummary](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectsummary)

Object has these attributes

```
[u'Acl', u'Bucket', u'MultipartUpload', u'Version', u'accept_ranges', u'bucket_name', u'cache_control', u'content_disposition', u'content_encoding', u'content_language', u'content_length', u'content_type', 'copy', u'copy_from', u'delete', u'delete_marker', 'download_file', 'download_fileobj', u'e_tag', u'expiration', u'expires', u'get', 'get_available_subresources', u'initiate_multipart_upload', u'key', u'last_modified', 'load', 'meta', u'metadata', u'missing_meta', u'parts_count', u'put', 'reload', u'replication_status', u'request_charged', u'restore', u'restore_object', u'server_side_encryption', u'sse_customer_algorithm', u'sse_customer_key_md5', u'ssekms_key_id', u'storage_class', 'upload_file', 'upload_fileobj', u'version_id', u'wait_until_exists', u'wait_until_not_exists', u'website_redirect_location']
```

ObjectSummary has these attributes

```
[u'Acl', u'Bucket', u'MultipartUpload', u'Object', u'Version', u'bucket_name', u'copy_from', u'delete', u'e_tag', u'get', 'get_available_subresources', u'initiate_multipart_upload', u'key', u'last_modified', 'load', 'meta', u'owner', u'put', u'restore_object', u'size', u'storage_class', u'wait_until_exists', u'wait_until_not_exists']
```