# Iterate through images using boto3 for pre-processing on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, attributeerror

I'm new to using boto3, and have looked at other questions but haven't seen the response I'm looking for.

I have some code which I am using to connect to a bucket in s3 that is storing my ML images. The processing code opens an image, allowing me to select certain label points in the image and save the points as an array.

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('bucket_name')
    images = my_bucket.objects.all()
    
    for obj in images:
        {processing code}
```

However, I am getting this error:

`AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute`

How can I access the actual object and not the ObjectSummary?

Comment: Did you check out this answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787642/aws-s3-object-has-no-attribute-server-side-encryption

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aws s3 - object has no attribute 'server\_side\_encryption'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787642/aws-s3-object-has-no-attribute-server-side-encryption)

Comment: Answered via Shawn here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787642/aws-s3-object-has-no-attribute-server-side-encryption